# Is there a way to avoid copying the whole search path of a binary tree on insert?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, binary-tree

I've just started working my way through Okasaki's [*Purely Functional Data Structures*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521663504), but have been doing things in Haskell rather than Standard ML. However, I've come across an early exercise (2.5) that's left me a bit stumped on how to do things in Haskell:

> Inserting an existing element into a binary search tree copies the entire search path 
>   even though the copied nodes are indistinguishable from the originals. Rewrite insert using exceptions to avoid this copying. Establish only one handler per insertion rather than one handler per iteration.

Now, my understanding is that ML, being an impure language, gets by with a conventional approach to  exception handling not so different to, say, Java's, so you can accomplish it something like this:

```
type Tree = E | T of Tree * int * Tree

exception ElementPresent

fun insert (x, t) = 
  let fun go E = T (E, x, E)
      fun go T(l, y, r) = 
             if      x < y then T(go (l), x, r)
             else if y < x then T(l, x, go (r))
             else    raise ElementPresent
  in go t
  end 
  handle ElementPresent => t
```

I don't have an ML implementation, so this may not be quite right in terms of the syntax.

My issue is that I have no idea how this can be done in Haskell, outside of doing everything in the `IO` monad, which seems like cheating and even if it's not cheating, would seriously limit the usefulness of a function which really **doesn't** do any mutation. I could use the `Maybe` monad:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Fork (Tree a) a (Tree a)
        deriving (Show)

insert     :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
insert x t = maybe t id (go t)
  where go Empty   = return (Fork Empty x Empty)
    go (Fork l y r)
      | x < y     = do l' <- go l; return (Fork l' y r)
      | x > y     = do r' <- go r; return (Fork l y r')
      | otherwise = Nothing
```

This means everything winds up wrapped in `Just` on the way back up when the element isn't found, which requires more heap allocation, and sort of defeats the purpose. Is this allocation just the price of purity?

**EDIT** to add: A lot of why I'm wondering about the suitability of the `Maybe` solution is that the optimization described only seems to save you all the constructor calls you would need in the case where the element already exists, which means heap allocations proportional to the length of the search path. The `Maybe` also avoids those constructor calls when the element already exists, but then you get a number of `Just` constructor calls equal to the length of the search path. I understand that a sufficiently smart compiler could elide all the `Just` allocations, but I don't know if, say, the current version of GHC is really that smart.

Comment: Wrapping in `Just` only adds `Just`, so you don't suddenly get heap abused: it is still the case that only a path is copied, not the whole tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of cost, the ML version is actually very similar to your Haskell version.

Every recursive call in the ML version results in a stack frame. The same is true in the
Haskell version. This is going to be proportional in size to the path that you traverse in
the tree. Also, both versions will of course allocate new nodes for the entire path if an insertion is actually performed.

In your Haskell version, every recursive call might also eventually result in the
allocation of a `Just` node. This will go on the minor heap, which is just a block of
memory with a bump pointer. For all practical purposes, GHC's minor heap is roughly equivalent in
cost to the stack. Since these are short-lived allocations, they won't normally end up
being moved to the major heap at all.

Answer (score 4):

GHC generally cannot elide path copying in cases like that. However, there is a way to do it manually, without incurring any of the indirection/allocation costs of `Maybe`. Here it is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}

import GHC.Prim (reallyUnsafePtrEquality#)

data Tree a = Empty | Fork (Tree a) a (Tree a)
        deriving (Show)

insert :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
insert x Empty = Fork Empty x Empty
insert x node@(Fork l y r)
    | x < y = let l' = insert x l in 
        case reallyUnsafePtrEquality# l l' of
            1# -> node
            _  -> Fork l' y r
    | x > y = let r' = insert x r in
        case reallyUnsafePtrEquality# r r' of
            1# -> node
            _  -> Fork l y r'
    | otherwise = node
```

The pointer equality function does exactly what's in the name. Here it is safe because even if the equality returns a false negative we only do a bit of extra copying, and nothing worse happens.

It's not the most idiomatic or prettiest Haskell, but the performance benefits can be significant. In fact, this trick is used very frequently in [`unordered-containers`](https://github.com/tibbe/unordered-containers/blob/master/Data/HashMap).

Comment: That's really interesting, but can you help me understand the mechanics here? So does that trick make the insert eager (would it work on an infinite tree)? Might `l'` and `r'` be thunks and would that cause `reallyUnsafePtrEquality#` to be false?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't the OP's original approach elide path copying?

Comment: @jberryman: as to the strictness, I intended the recursive case to be strict, but I totally forgot the bang patterns (I edited the answer now). Thunks would indeed make pointer equality false, and so this doesn't work on infinite trees. But binary search trees (and pretty much all associative containers in Haskell Platform) are spine-strict anyway, so this isn't an issue here. Also, pointer equality can return false negatives because of GC pointer copying at any time.

Comment: @dfeuer it does, and it could well provide performance boost when there are lots of redundant insertions, but as OP points out it also adds some overhead (and the pointer check also has overhead, of course, but much less).

Comment: I'm not seeing why the pointer check is all that different. It seems that the essence of either approach is the hope that the "call stack" is managed *as a stack*, so if the search paths are short enough, you can make good use of the CPU caches even with many aborted insertions, by (essentially) popping the postponed constructors off the stack. If the search paths are *long*, however, this seems likely to slow things down, because items evicted from cache on the way down must be brought back on the way up, and we would be better off constructing the unneeded path and (cont)

Comment: (cont) then letting it fall out of the cache. I don't know just how GHC ends up compiling those `Maybe`s, but logically speaking all that's needed is a single boolean flag to indicate whether the item was found in the tree. That is, without seeing benchmarks, it's not immediately clear to *me* that the unsafe pointer comparison should be much faster. More experienced people may know reasons for that to be the case, of course.

Comment: @dfeuer GHC uses constructor tags on the pointers themselves (for up to 7 constructors on 64 bit systems), so the `Nothing` case is pretty much branching on a boolean flag. However, the `Just` case does one heap allocation for the constructor and subsequently one dereference, for each tree node, which is where the bulk of the cost lies. With pointer comparison both dereference and allocation are avoided (alternatively, we could emulate `Maybe` by returning `(# Int#, a #)` unboxed tuples, which has the additional benefit of being safe and deterministic).

Answer (score 2):

As fizruk indicates, the `Maybe` approach is not significantly different from what you'd get in Standard ML. Yes, the whole path is copied, but the new copy is discarded if it turns out not to be needed. The `Just` constructor itself may not even be allocated on the heap—it can't escape from `insert`, let alone the module, and you don't do anything weird with it, so the compiler is free to analyze it to death.

#### Edit

There are efficiency problems, now that I think of it. Your use of `Maybe` conceals the fact that you're actually making two passes—one down to find the insertion point and one up to build the tree. The solution to this is to drop `Maybe Tree` in favor of `(Tree,Bool)` and use strictness annotations, or to switch to continuation-passing style. Also, if you choose to stay with the three-way logic, you may want to use the three-way comparison function. Alternatively, you can go all the way to the bottom each time and check later if you hit a duplicate.

Comment: Is the whole path really copied if the innermost recursive call returns `Nothing`? No constructor should be applied in that case, skipping allocation completely. The `Just` values are allocated, but eliminated immediately, so they have a very short life, and should be GC'd quite soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a predicate that checks whether the key is already in the tree, you can look before you leap:

```
insert x t  =  if contains t x then t else insert' x t
```

This traverses the tree twice, of course. Whether that's as bad as it sounds should be determined empirically: it might just load the relevant part of the tree into the cache.

Comment: I've fixed the title. As for traversing the tree twice, it may not be a big problem, but then again, copying the nodes in the search path is not going to be a problem in a lot of cases either.